# harmonic balance method for a 2-mass 3-spring system

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am trying to solve a nonlinear 3spring-2mass system under harmonic loading by using Fourier series expansion of states of the differential equation. The system is just basically two masses, two linear and one nonlinear spring (elastic perfectly plastic hysteretic material nonlinearity) between two masses. It is kind of a challenging but I am sure it is pretty straightforward for some people to find out the issue I am having. So if anyone can take his/her time and help me understand the issue better, I would be very thankful.

$x$ is being displacement of first mass; $u=x_{2}-x_{1}$ being relative displacement; $w_1=k_1/m_1$ and $w_2=k_2/m_2$ are being frequency of first and and second masses; $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ being damping parameter; $f$ being the restoring from the nonlinear spring between two masses; and $z0$ being the excitation amplitude; the equations of motion of two masses are given as:

$\ddot{u}+\ddot{x}+w_{2}^{2}(u+x)+2\xi_{2}w_{2}(\dot{u}+\dot{x})+\frac{f}{m_{2}}=-z_{0}sin(wt)$

$\ddot{x}+w_{1}^{2}x+2\xi_{1}w_{1}\dot{x}-\frac{f}{m_{1}}=-z_{0}sin(wt)$

[Problem Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHS8v.jpg)

where

$x=x_{a1}cos(wt)+x_{b1}sin(wt)+x_{a3}cos(3wt)+x_{b3}sin(3wt)+...$
$u=u_{a1}cos(wt)+u_{b1}sin(wt)+u_{a3}cos(3wt)+u_{b3}sin(3wt)+...$
$f=f_{a1}cos(wt)+f_{b1}sin(wt)+f_{a3}cos(3wt)+f_{b3}sin(3wt)+...$

note that $f$ is hysteretic restoring force (which is very close to a rectangle).

Notes:

- Main code is "HBM7_StickSlipCombSolution02.m"
- $f$ is approximated in "fn_func_obtain.m" as a fourier series for initial assumption of amplitude of $u$ as $u_{0init}$
- There are four m-files below, but there is no problem when the system is linear; thence there is no need on looking at "HBM1_StickSolutionFcn.m" code. The issue comes when the system is nonlinear where "HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn.m" is used for solving the system.
- The response is nonlinear on only four frequency steps (steps 8-to-11, corresponding to 0.8-to-1.1 in the X-axis of the frequency plot below) and there is an issue on this nonlinear range as described below.
- The codes I provided consider first, third, fifth, and seventh harmonics.
- All the damping terms are ignored: $\xi_{1} = \xi_{2} = \xi_{3} = 0$ and can be ignored in equations above. For general purpose, they are included in codes. Note that \xi_{3} is not adapted inside equations yet since it requires another fourier series approximation, so just ignore those terms in the codes.
- The harmonic balance method applied to equations of motion by substituting $x$ and $u$ equations, meaning that all the coefficient terms of each harmonic $(cos(wt), sin(wt), cos(3wt),...)$ on the left side of equations will be equal to corresponding right hand side harmonics, but notice that on the right hand side there is only sin(wt) terms; thence most of the right hand side of equations will be zero.
- For assumed initial value of $u_0$, the derived 16 equations for 1,3,5,7 harmonics are solved by using "fsolve" of matlab.
- For every assumed $u_0$ value, responses are obtained and $u$ therefore $u_0$ is calculated and checked if it is equal to initial assumption $u_{0init}$

If we look at the results, convergence is obtained pretty well and assumed $u_{0init}$ and $u_{0}$ from response has very small difference (about 10^-10 ranges). But the response from the third harmonic is extremely large, which doesn't make sense. Only considering first harmonic terms in the response gives meaningful results, but I couldn't figure out why I get very large amplitude values for the 3rd harmonic. Please see the code and see the figure below. Note that $x_1=x$ and $x_2=x+u$

[Response of x_1=x and x_2=x+u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYr0.jpg)

I am just pasting the code here. I appreciate if someone can put it in better format. There are four m-files below.

I really appreciate if someone can help me explain why I m getting very large response of $x$ on the third harmonic.

1) Main Code - HBM7_StickSlipCombSolution02.m:

> clear all; clc;
>
> muval = 5;
>
> M_1 = 43.9; % kips/g, Total mass
>
> m1val = M_1/(1+muval);  % 1/11*M_1
>
> k1val = 1386;
>
> k2val=k1val*0.04;
>
> m2val  = M_1-m1val;
>
> alpha_yield = 0.5;
>
> Fpx = 12*540.9;
>
> fy3 = alpha_yield*Fpx;
>
> ry3 = 0.1;
>
> IniStiffIFAS = fy3/ry3;
>
> k3val = IniStiffIFAS;
>
> wn_rig = sqrt((k1val+k2val)/(m1val+m2val));
>
> w = (0.1*wn_rig):(0.1*wn_rig):(4*wn_rig);
>
> Xi1 = 0.00000;
>
> Xi2 = 0.00000;
>
> Xi3 = 0.0; % Don't use this for now b/c it is not adapted in slip case yet
>
> g_grav = 386; % g, in/s^2
>
> z0 = 0.1*g_grav; % z0, ground excitation amplitude (F0)
>
> Xst_rig = z0*(m1val+m2val)/(k1val+k2val);
>
> StickFlagCheck = zeros(length(w),1); % stick check
>
> SlipFlagCheck  = zeros(length(w),1); % slip check
>
> Delta_u0_Opt_store = zeros(length(w),1); % check DeltaPhi is small in slip case
>
> u0_ini0 = 1; % initial guess for u0 = x2-x1
>
> fn_fcn = fn_func_obtain;
>
> Slip_inds = []; % store slip case index
>
> tic;
>
> for j=1:length(w);
>
> j
>
> Wval = w(j);
>
> % STICK CASE: start with stick case assumption and check if stick happens
>
> w1 = sqrt(k1val/m1val); % 2*pi;
>
> w2 = sqrt((k2val+k3val)/m2val); % 2*pi;
>
> Params = [w1 w2 Wval Xi1 Xi2 Xi3 z0 muval k1val k2val k3val ry3];
>
> [y,StickFlag] = HBM1_StickSolutionFcn(Params);
>
> % If slip occurs, use SLIP CASE equations
>
> if strcmp(StickFlag,'StickCase_NOT_TRUE');
>
> Slip_inds = [Slip_inds j];
>
> w1 = sqrt(k1val/m1val);
>
> w2 = sqrt(k2val/m2val);
>
> Nfourier = 7;
>
> Params = [w1 w2 Wval Xi1 Xi2 Xi3 z0 fy3 ry3 m1val m2val k2val Nfourier];
>
> % Global Search Algorithm
>
> ObjectiveFunc = @(u0_ini)HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn(u0_ini,Params,fn_fcn);
>
> gs = GlobalSearch; % gs.NumTrialPoints = 1e5; % gs.MaxTime = 300;
>
> ms = MultiStart(gs);
>
> opts = optimoptions(@fmincon);
>
> Lowbound = 0.001;
>
> Upbound  = 40*Xst_rig; % 'fmincon'
>
> Prob = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',u0_ini0,'objective',ObjectiveFunc,...
>
> ```
> 'lb',Lowbound,'options',opts); % 'lb',Lowbound,'ub',Upbound,'options',opts);
> ```
>
> u0_ini_range = 0.1:0.5:Upbound;
>
> [u0_iniGrid] = ndgrid(u0_ini_range);
>
> W = u0_iniGrid(:);
>
> bigstart = CustomStartPointSet(W);
>
> tic;
>
> [u0_OptVal Delta_u0_Opt] = run(ms,Prob,bigstart);
>
> toc;
>
> Delta_u0_Opt_store(j) = Delta_u0_Opt;
>
> % now get results with the optimal Phi value (PhiOptVal)
>
> [Delta_u0, y_opt, fval] = HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn(u0_OptVal,Params,fn_fcn);
>
> u0_ini0 = u0_OptVal;
>
> y1 = y_opt;
>
> xa1 = y1(1);  xb1 = y1(2);  xa3 = y1(3);  xb3 = y1(4);
>
> ua1 = y1(5);  ub1 = y1(6);  ua3 = y1(7);  ub3 = y1(8);
>
> xa5 = y1(9);  xb5 = y1(10); xa7 = y1(11); xb7 = y1(12);
>
> ua5 = y1(13); ub5 = y1(14); ua7 = y1(15); ub7 = y1(16);
>
> t = 0:0.01:500;
>
> U0_out00_1(:,j) = ua1*cos(Wval*t)+ub1*sin(Wval*t);
>
> U0_out00_3(:,j) = ua3*cos(3*Wval*t)+ub3*sin(3*Wval*t);
>
> U0_out00_5(:,j) = ua5*cos(5*Wval*t)+ub5*sin(5*Wval*t);
>
> U0_out00_7(:,j) = ua7*cos(7*Wval*t)+ub7*sin(7*Wval*t);
>
> U0_out00(:,j)   = U0_out00_1(:,j)+U0_out00_3(:,j)+U0_out00_5(:,j)+U0_out00_7(:,j);
>
> U0_out = max(abs(U0_out00(:,j)));
>
> X0_out00_1(:,j) = xa1*cos(Wval*t)+xb1*sin(Wval*t);
>
> X0_out00_3(:,j) = xa3*cos(3*Wval*t)+xb3*sin(3*Wval*t);
>
> X0_out00_5(:,j) = xa5*cos(5*Wval*t)+xb5*sin(5*Wval*t);
>
> X0_out00_7(:,j) = xa7*cos(7*Wval*t)+xb7*sin(7*Wval*t);
>
> X0_out00(:,j) = X0_out00_1(:,j)+X0_out00_3(:,j)+X0_out00_5(:,j)+X0_out00_7(:,j);
>
> X0_out = max(abs(X0_out00(:,j)));
>
> X0b2_out00 = U0_out00(:,j)+X0_out00(:,j);
>
> X0b2_out = max(abs(X0b2_out00));
>
> % Check if Slip Case is "TRUE"
>
> U0SlipCheck = U0_out;
>
> if U0SlipCheck > ry3; SlipFlagCheck(j) = 2; % 'SlipCase_TRUE';
>
> else SlipFlagCheck(j) = 0; % 'SlipCase_NOT_TRUE';
>
> end
>
> % Store SLIP case results
>
> X0_j(j)  = X0_out;
>
> U0_j(j)  = U0_out;
>
> X0b2_j(j) = X0b2_out;
>
> else % slip case didn't occur so get results of stick case below
>
> y1 = y;
>
> x1 = y1(1);
>
> x2 = y1(2);
>
> u1 = y1(3);
>
> u2 = y1(4);
>
> % Check if Slip Case is "TRUE"
>
> U0StickCheck = sqrt(u1^2+u2^2);
>
> if U0StickCheck <= ry3; StickFlagCheck(j) = 1; % 'StickCase_TRUE';
>
> else StickFlagCheck(j) = 0; % 'StickCase_NOT_TRUE';
>
> end
>
> % Store STICK case results
>
> X0_j(j)  = sqrt(x1^2+x2^2);
>
> U0_j(j)  = sqrt(u1^2+u2^2);
>
> X0b2_j(j) = sqrt((u1+x1)^2+(u2+x2)^2);
>
> end
>
> end
>
> toc;
>
> %% Slip_inds; X0_j; X0b2_j; U0_j;
>
> X0_out_I1 = X0_j; X0_out_I3 = X0_j; X0_out_I5 = X0_j; X0_out_I7 = X0_j;
>
> U0_out_I1 = U0_j; U0_out_I3 = U0_j; U0_out_I5 = U0_j; U0_out_I7 = U0_j;
>
> X0b2_out_I1 = X0b2_j; X0b2_out_I3 = X0b2_j; X0b2_out_I5 = X0b2_j; X0b2_out_I7 = X0b2_j;
>
> Slip_inds; % slip index
>
> N_slip = size(Slip_inds,2);
>
> for j = 1:N_slip
>
> U0_out00_I1 = U0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> U0_out00_I3 = U0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j))+U0_out00_3(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> U0_out00_I5 = U0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j))+U0_out00_3(:,Slip_inds(j))+U0_out00_5(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> U0_out00_I7 = U0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j))+U0_out00_3(:,Slip_inds(j))+U0_out00_5(:,Slip_inds(j))+U0_out00_7(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> U0_out_I1(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(U0_out00_I1));
>
> U0_out_I3(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(U0_out00_I3));
>
> U0_out_I5(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(U0_out00_I5));
>
> U0_out_I7(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(U0_out00_I7));
>
> %%%
>   X0_out00_I1 = X0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> X0_out00_I3 = X0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j))+X0_out00_3(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> X0_out00_I5 = X0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j))+X0_out00_3(:,Slip_inds(j))+X0_out00_5(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> X0_out00_I7 = X0_out00_1(:,Slip_inds(j))+X0_out00_3(:,Slip_inds(j))+X0_out00_5(:,Slip_inds(j))+X0_out00_7(:,Slip_inds(j));
>
> X0_out_I1(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0_out00_I1));
>
> X0_out_I3(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0_out00_I3));
>
> X0_out_I5(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0_out00_I5));
>
> X0_out_I7(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0_out00_I7));
>
> X0b2_out00_I1 = X0_out00_I1+U0_out00_I1;
>
> X0b2_out00_I3 = X0_out00_I3+U0_out00_I3;
>
> X0b2_out00_I5 = X0_out00_I5+U0_out00_I5;
>
> X0b2_out00_I7 = X0_out00_I7+U0_out00_I7;
>
> X0b2_out_I1(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0b2_out00_I1));
>
> X0b2_out_I3(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0b2_out00_I3));
>
> X0b2_out_I5(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0b2_out00_I5));
>
> X0b2_out_I7(Slip_inds(j)) = max(abs(X0b2_out00_I7));
>
> end
>
> %%
>   figure;
>
> subplot 211
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0_out_I1/Xst_rig,'-k','linewidth',2); hold on all;
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0_out_I3/Xst_rig,'-b','linewidth',2);
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0_out_I5/Xst_rig,'--g','linewidth',2);
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0_out_I7/Xst_rig,'-.r','linewidth',2);
>
> ylabel('X_1/X_{st, rig}'); xlabel('w / w_{n, rig}'); axis tight; grid minor;
>
> subplot 212
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0b2_out_I1/Xst_rig,'-k','linewidth',2); hold on all;
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0b2_out_I3/Xst_rig,'-b','linewidth',2);
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0b2_out_I5/Xst_rig,'--g','linewidth',2);
>
> plot(w/wn_rig, X0b2_out_I7/Xst_rig,'-.r','linewidth',2);
>
> ylabel('X_2/X_{st, rig}'); xlabel('w / w_{n, rig}'); axis tight; grid minor;

2) Second Code - HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn.m:

> function [Delta_u0,y1,fval] = HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn(u0_ini,Params,fn_fcn)
>
> w1  = Params(1);
>    w2  = Params(2);
>    w   = Params(3);
>    Xi1 = Params(4);
>    Xi2 = Params(5);
>    Xi3 = Params(6);
>    z0  = Params(7);
>    Fy  = Params(8);
>    ry3 = Params(9);
>    m1  = Params(10);
>    m2  = Params(11);
>    k2  = Params(12);
>    Nfourier = Params(13);
>
> A = @(Cinit)FindRootsSlip02hbm3(Cinit,Params,fn_fcn,u0_ini);
>
> Cinit = zeros(16,1);
>    options = optimset('Display','off');
>
> [Coeff,fval,exitflag,output] = fsolve(A,Cinit,options);
>
> y1 = Coeff;
>
> xa1 = Coeff(1);  xb1 = Coeff(2);  xa3 = Coeff(3);  xb3 = Coeff(4);
>
> ua1 = Coeff(5);  ub1 = Coeff(6);  ua3 = Coeff(7);  ub3 = Coeff(8);
>
> xa5 = Coeff(9);  xb5 = Coeff(10); xa7 = Coeff(11); xb7 = Coeff(12);
>
> ua5 = Coeff(13); ub5 = Coeff(14); ua7 = Coeff(15); ub7 = Coeff(16);
>
> t = 0:0.01:500;
>
> U0_out00 = ua1*cos(w*t)+ub1*sin(w*t)+ ua3*cos(3*w*t)+ub3*sin(3*w*t)+...
>               ua5*cos(5*w*t)+ub5*sin(5*w*t)+ua7*cos(7*w*t)+ub7*sin(7*w*t);
>
> U0_out = max(abs(U0_out00));
>
> X0_out00 = xa1*cos(w*t)+xb1*sin(w*t)+ xa3*cos(3*w*t)+xb3*sin(3*w*t)+...
>               xa5*cos(5*w*t)+xb5*sin(5*w*t)+xa7*cos(7*w*t)+xb7*sin(7*w*t);
>
> X0_out = max(abs(X0_out00));
>
> dbstop if warning
>
> Delta_u0 = abs(u0_ini - U0_out);

3) Third Code - HBM1_StickSolutionFcn.m:

> function [y1,StickFlag] = HBM1_StickSolutionFcn(Params)
>
> w1    = Params(1);
>     w2    = Params(2);
>     w     = Params(3);
>     Xi1   = Params(4);
>     Xi2   = Params(5);
>     Xi3   = Params(6);
>     z0    = Params(7);
>     Mu    = Params(8);
>     k1val = Params(9);
>     k2val = Params(10);
>     k3val = Params(11);
>     ry3   = Params(12);
>
> k21 = k2val/k1val;
>     k31 = k3val/k1val;
>
> A = [-w^2+k21*w1^2/Mu      2*Xi2*w2*w           -w^2+w2^2         2*Xi2*w2*w+2*Xi3*w2*w;
>            -2*Xi2*w2*w      -w^2+k21*w1^2/Mu  -2*Xi2*w2*w-2*Xi3*w2*w        -w^2+w2^2      ;
>             -w^2+w1^2          2*Xi1*w1*w           -k31*w1^2              -2*Xi3*w2*Mu*w  ;
>            -2*Xi1*w1*w         -w^2+w1^2           2*Xi3*w2*Mu*w            -k31*w1^2     ];
>     B = [-z0; 0; -z0; 0];
>     y1 = A\B;
>     x1 = y1(1); x2 = y1(2);
>     u1 = y1(3); u2 = y1(4);
>     U0 = sqrt(u1^2+u2^2);
>
> % Check if Stick Case is "TRUE"
>
> if U0 <= ry3;
>         StickFlag = 'StickCase_TRUE';
>         disp(StickFlag)
>     else
>         StickFlag = 'StickCase_NOT_TRUE';
>         disp(StickFlag)
>     end

4) Forth Code - FindRootsSlip02hbm3.m:

> function A = FindRootsSlip02hbm3(Cinit,Params,fn_fcn,u0_ini)
>
> w1  = Params(1);
>    w2  = Params(2);
>    w   = Params(3);
>    Xi1 = Params(4);
>    Xi2 = Params(5);
>    Xi3 = Params(6);
>    z0  = Params(7);
>    Fy  = Params(8);
>    ry3 = Params(9);
>    m1  = Params(10);
>    m2  = Params(11);
>    k2  = Params(12);
>    Nfourier = Params(13);
>    %
>    mu = m2/m1;
>
> kf = Fy/ry3; % initial stiffness
>
> xa1 = Cinit(1); xb1 = Cinit(2); xa3 = Cinit(3); xb3 = Cinit(4);
>
> ua1 = Cinit(5); ub1 = Cinit(6); ua3 = Cinit(7); ub3 = Cinit(8);
>
> xa5 = Cinit(9);  xb5 = Cinit(10); xa7 = Cinit(11); xb7 = Cinit(12);
>
> ua5 = Cinit(13); ub5 = Cinit(14); ua7 = Cinit(15); ub7 = Cinit(16);
>
> Theta0 = acos(1-2*ry3/u0_ini);
>
> fa1_f = fn_fcn.fa1; fb1_f = fn_fcn.fb1; fa3_f = fn_fcn.fa3; fb3_f = fn_fcn.fb3;
>
> fa5_f = fn_fcn.fa5; fb5_f = fn_fcn.fb5; fa7_f = fn_fcn.fa7; fb7_f = fn_fcn.fb7;
>
> fa1 = fa1_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> fb1 = fb1_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> fa3 = fa3_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> fb3 = fb3_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> fa5 = fa5_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> fb5 = fb5_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> fa7 = fa7_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> fb7 = fb7_f(Fy,Theta0,kf,u0_ini);
>
> wa1 = 0; wb1 = 0; wa3 = 0; wb3 = 0;
>
> wa5 = 0; wb5 = 0; wa7 = 0; wb7 = 0;
>
> Y = acos(ua1/u0_ini);
>
> cosY = cos(Y); sinY = sin(Y);
>
> cos3Y = cos(3*Y); sin3Y = sin(3*Y);
>
> cos5Y = cos(5*Y); sin5Y = sin(5*Y);
>
> cos7Y = cos(7*Y); sin7Y = sin(7*Y);
>
> A(1)  = -w^2*xa1-w^2*ua1+w2^2*xa1+w2^2*ua1+2*Xi2*w2*w*xb1+2*Xi2*w2*w*ub1+2*Xi3*wa1+1/m2*(fa1*cosY-fb1*sinY);
>
> A(2)  = -w^2*xb1-w^2*ub1+w2^2*xb1+w2^2*ub1-2*Xi2*w2*w*xa1-2*Xi2*w2*w*ua1+2*Xi3*wb1+1/m2*(fa1*sinY+fb1*cosY)+z0;
>
> A(3)  = -9*w^2*xa3-9*w^2*ua3+w2^2*xa3+w2^2*ua3+6*Xi2*w2*w*xb3+6*Xi2*w2*w*ub3+2*Xi3*wa3+1/m2*(fa3*cos3Y-fb3*sin3Y);
>
> A(4)  = -9*w^2*xb3-9*w^2*ub3+w2^2*xb3+w2^2*ub3-6*Xi2*w2*w*xa3-6*Xi2*w2*w*ua3+2*Xi3*wb3+1/m2*(fa3*sin3Y+fb3*cos3Y);
>
> A(5)  = -25*w^2*xa5-25*w^2*ua5+w2^2*xa5+w2^2*ua5+10*Xi2*w2*w*xb5+10*Xi2*w2*w*ub5+2*Xi3*wa5+1/m2*(fa5*cos5Y-fb5*sin5Y);
>
> A(6)  = -25*w^2*xb5-25*w^2*ub5+w2^2*xb5+w2^2*ub5-10*Xi2*w2*w*xa5-10*Xi2*w2*w*ua5+2*Xi3*wb5+1/m2*(fa5*sin5Y+fb5*cos5Y);
>
> A(7)  = -49*w^2*xa7-49*w^2*ua7+w2^2*xa7+w2^2*ua7+14*Xi2*w2*w*xb7+14*Xi2*w2*w*ub7+2*Xi3*wa7+1/m2*(fa7*cos7Y-fb7*sin7Y);
>
> A(8)  = -49*w^2*xb7-49*w^2*ub7+w2^2*xb7+w2^2*ub7-14*Xi2*w2*w*xa7-14*Xi2*w2*w*ua7+2*Xi3*wb7+1/m2*(fa7*sin7Y+fb7*cos7Y);
>
> A(9)  = -w^2*xa1+w1^2*xa1+2*Xi1*w1*w*xb1-2*Xi3*mu*wa1-1/m1*(fa1*cosY-fb1*sinY);
>
> A(10)  = -w^2*xb1+w1^2*xb1-2*Xi1*w1*w*xa1-2*Xi3*mu*wb1-1/m1*(fa1*sinY+fb1*cosY)+z0;
>
> A(11)  = -9*w^2*xa3+w1^2*xa3+6*Xi1*w1*w*xb3-2*Xi3*mu*wa3-1/m1*(fa3*cos3Y-fb3*sin3Y);
>
> A(12)  = -9*w^2*xb3+w1^2*xb3-6*Xi1*w1*w*xa3-2*Xi3*mu*wb3-1/m1*(fa3*sin3Y+fb3*cos3Y);
>
> A(13)  = -25*w^2*xa5+w1^2*xa5+10*Xi1*w1*w*xb5-2*Xi3*mu*wa5-1/m1*(fa5*cos5Y-fb5*sin5Y);
>
> A(14)  = -25*w^2*xb5+w1^2*xb5-10*Xi1*w1*w*xa5-2*Xi3*mu*wb5-1/m1*(fa5*sin5Y+fb5*cos5Y);
>
> A(15)  = -49*w^2*xa7+w1^2*xa7+14*Xi1*w1*w*xb7-2*Xi3*mu*wa7-1/m1*(fa7*cos7Y-fb7*sin7Y);
>
> A(16)  = -49*w^2*xb7+w1^2*xb7-14*Xi1*w1*w*xa7-2*Xi3*mu*wb7-1/m1*(fa7*sin7Y+fb7*cos7Y);

Comment: Is this question a repeat of your earlier one http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227727

Comment: I deleted the earlier question because I was not able to modify it. And I added the matlab code here, which will give more information about the problem. Please let me know if you have any ideas about the issues I am having in the problem.

And could you put an exclamation before two pictures in here? it is still not allowing me...

Comment: Is there anyone who has any idea about the issue? I really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't complete solution to this problem but I figured out why I was not able to obtain the solution. Once I figure out, I will post the code here as well.

So the issue is related to the phase shift between the response frequency of masses and the frequency of the applied load that I have to include in equations. This fixation started giving me meaningful results.